# Pokemon GO More XP Depending On Which Evolution Stage

Tags: pokemon-go

My question is do you get more XP in Pokemon GO for evolving a Pokemon (that is able to evolve 2 times) from their middle stage to their final stage than you do for evolving them from their first stage to their second stage?  I would inherently think so because to evolve a Pokemon from their second stage to their final stage requires more candy than from evolving them from their first stage to their second stage.

Here is an example with Pidgey:
Would you get more XP from evolving Pidgey -> Pidgeotto or Pidgeotto -> Pidgeot?
Or does Pokemon GO just give the user a flat amount of XP for evolving a Pokemon?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It provides the same XP. 500xp per evolution and 500xp extra if you dont have the evolution you obtain